# Higher Order Scala Func

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala Higher Order Function and i am kind of confuse in this. 
Up to my knowledge , HOF can take functions as arguments like

```
val c = (x:Int)=> x + 3
```

here it means it take one argument of type Int and returns Int.

But i am not able to understand the below code as  it take a functions as argument of type Int => Int but  means it takes one argument and returns Int , but while implementing this they are sending a function which takes two Int args.

```
    def calculate(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int) =
  if (b != 0) f(a, b) else throw Exception("Divide by 0")

def divide(a: Int, b: Int) = a / b

calculate(divide, 2, 0) // => Exception
calculate(divide, 4, 2) // => 2
```

Can someone help me in understanding this.
I appreciate if someone can share some code links where i can understand more about HOF.

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: `val c = (x:Int)=> x + 3` is not a higher order function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def divide(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a / b
```

`divide` is a function (actually a method) that takes 2 `Int`s and returns 1 `Int`.  It can also be written like this.

```
val divide = (a:Int, b:Int) => a/b
```

In this case it is an actual function, but the difference between method and function need not concern us here.

```
def calculate(f: (Int, Int) => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int = ...
```

`calculate` take 3 arguments. The first, `f`, is a function that takes 2 `Int`s and returns 1 `Int`. (Note the correct signature.)

```
calculate(divide, 77, 7)
```

Invoke `calculate` with `divide` as its first argument.  Inside the `calculate` code `divide` is referenced (renamed) as `f` and invoked as such. So `f(a, b)` is really `divide(77, 7)`.

Comment: Thnx  @jwvh  for explanation , so if `def calculate(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int) =` , in this we can send any function which take only one Integer and return Int , we can send a function with two args only when we have `def calculate(f: (Int, Int) => Int, a: Int, b: Int)` .
However we can not send a function with two args in `def calculate(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int) =` since it only take a function with one args. i hope i understood it correctly .